# Android Fragment and thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I'm using `FragmentActivity` to swap two tabs. That is tab A and tab B. In Tab B I'm using `ListView` with Loadmore button, when suppose the loadmore button clicked I just called backgroud thread.

```
private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog (
                getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        try {
            //service url to fectch data..
            //xml parsing
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response = "failure";
            System.out.println(" sec XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        int currentPosition = listViewattlist.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        // Appending new data to menuItems ArrayList
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.att_list, R.id.title, data);
        listViewattlist.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Setting new scroll position
        listViewattlist.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
        return (null);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // closing progress dialog
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

When I swap and clicked that button I am able to see the progressbar but it shows the error as below:

```
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:867)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10250)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10205)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:190)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:350)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setVisible(Drawable.java:546)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.widget.ImageView.onDetachedFromWindow(ImageView.java:1173)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:11789)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2532)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout(ViewGroup.java:3819)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1936)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:502)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:442)

07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at com.owentech.testswipeab.TabTwo$loadMoreListView.doInBackground(TabTwo.java:372)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at com.owentech.testswipeab.TabTwo$loadMoreListView.doInBackground(TabTwo.java:1)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-13 11:42:29.386: E/AndroidRuntime(894): ... 5 more

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

`doInBackground()` executes in other thread. In `doInBackground()` you try to update `listViewattlist`, which was created in the UI-thread. This is a mistake, and you should update `listViewattlist` in your `onPostExecute()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot touch your `View` objects from separate threads, and you know that `doInBackground()` runs in a separate thread. So the calls to the `ListView` will result in an exception thrown. Move all `View`-touching code to `onPostExecute()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you all .. this alsoi wanna include in my code because am ruuning that in 4.0 SDk  static{
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>14)
    {
       StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

       StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
   }      this seems higher os version 4.0 emultor.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the UI from your background thread which is not possible.

1. You can see the progressbar, as preExceute is doing its job fine
2. In the doInBackground you are trying to set the adapter on the main activity UI which is wrong. doInBackground is for background processes and please annotate the function(@Override)
3. Something about debugging:- see the error message in your log "Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" ..This line should have actually told you what you are doing wrong