# ListView wont show in ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I've been trying to fix a problem that I'm facing for hours now;
My ViewPagerIndicator works fine, I can switch properly between tabs and even can see the content in Fragments properly as long as it's not a ViewList... The ViewPager can't seem to display any ListView in any way!

Note: 
-when hovering over android.support.v4.view.ViewPager I get a "This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found"; I don't know if it's related to my problem since it wasn't mention when I was searching a fix.

-the setAdapter(..) (to set the content of my ListView) won't work also; I guess it's related to the problem also.

Please if anyone can help me I'd apperciate it.

Thanks in advance.

(Will post my code if anyone is willing to help :) )

**EDIT:**

Thanks a lot Yatin for your quick reply :) I have 4 tabs that I can switch between.. for testing I made a tab which contains a button and a listview.. the button is displayed properly but the listview wont show...

bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainbottom"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/secondlist"
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:layout_height="721dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.45"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="650dp">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#2FB3E3"
        app:footerColor="#2FB3E3"
        app:footerLineHeight="1dp"
        app:footerIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:footerIndicatorStyle="underline"
        app:selectedColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:selectedBold="true"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentAdapter.java

```
  public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) 
{
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new FirstActivity();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        fragment = new FirstActivity();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new SecondActivity();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new ThirdActivity();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new FourthActivity();
        break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 4;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    String title = "";
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        title = "First";
        break;
    case 1:
        title = "Second";
        break;
    case 2:
        title = "Third";
        break;
    case 3:
        title = "Fourth";
        break;
    }
    return title;
}

}
```

Comment: I'd be happy to take a look. Please post your code.

Comment: It may be as simple as this.  Try it out and post if that doesn't work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465227/android-fragment-and-thread

Comment: No luck.. I'll retry tomorrow to find any solution.. thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've solved my problem...

I was using a custom adapter for my listview in the main activity; I've modified this adapter for a fragment and used it in the FirstActivity() instead in the MainActivity().